# how to include header files and sources from different project in makefile

Tags: makefile

I have included a header of another project in my main.cxx file . I want to build my simple program in makefile. Is there a way to do it? Following is the illustration of how files are stored.

```
Another Project Main Folder        
       -Folder A                  
            -Folder B             
               -Include folder    
                     - file.h
Test Folder
       -main.cxx
```

Comment: I presume you want to execute the build in `Test Folder/`. Do your directory names really have spaces in them?

Comment: What did you try? -I not working? (That's a dash and an uppercase i). In other words: Yes, there is a way. But as Beta has mentioned, spaces might lead to trouble. And if you can't give the include folder with relative paths, it could get difficult on Windows if you have a Version of make that doesn't like Windows drive leters. So, next question: What system, what make version, what compiler?

Comment: What is the question here exactly? How to include the header in the makefile? How to get the compiler to find the header file correctly?

Comment: @Beta There are no spaces in the folder names, just for the sake of illustration I have used dummy folder names. Yes, I want to include file.h in main.cxx but if I create a simple makefile, it wont find file.h, because it is in another folder directory.

Comment: @Sebastian I am working on ubuntu 14.04 LTS, GNU Make 3.81 and gcc 4.8.2

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes, I want compiler to find the header file. It would be helpful if you can tell me how it can be done on both command line and also in makefile, since I want to learn how to create makefile to build projects.

Comment: You need to give make the path to the file, whatever that path is, as a prerequisite of whatever target you want make to use it for. Similarly, you need to use `-I` (or similar) flags to your compiler to give it additional paths to search for when using "local" include files.

Comment: Yes! I manage to give the path of the file by using -I compiler flag, then used -L flag to give the path of object files.It seems to work.